# Unit test in Django: using self.assertIn() to find text in key/value pair

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, dictionary

I'm trying to write a unit test for my Django app using `self.assertIn()`

This is my unit test:

```
    def test_user_get_apps_meta(self):
        myuser = User.objects.get(email='theemail@gmail.com')
        tagline = 'the text'
        self.assertIn(tagline, myuser.get_apps())
```

The result of `myuser.get_apps()` is a list of dictionaries.  In one of those dictionaries is indeed the `tagline` text I'm looking for: `'the text'`

But I'm getting an error when I run the test:

```
    self.assertIn(tagline, myuser.get_apps())
    AssertionError: 'the text' not found in [{'logo_app_alt': 'the text', '...},{},{}]
```

Am I not using `self.assertIn()` correctly?  Is there a way to check if certain text is the value of a key/value pair in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found, `self.assertIn(tagline, taglines)` will only work if `taglines` contains the actual string. It won't work if it contains a dictionary that has the string as a value.

You could use a list comprehension to extract the values from the dictionaries, and pass that to `self.assertIn`:

```
    expected_tagline = 'the text'
    taglines = [d['logo_app_alt'] for d in myuser.get_apps()]
    self.assertIn(expected_tagline, taglines)
```